# Keep display turned off despite notifications. Only turn display back on when human interaction occurs

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a Dell Latitude E6510 running Windows 7 professional. Is there a way to configure the computer to, when the display is turned off, only turn back on when the user interacts with it (e.g. mouse movement, keystroke). The reason I want this is because I sometimes do backups or virus scans at night. I turn off the display after I start them, but they often turn back on for some reason or another and the light generated from the laptop is quite tough to ignore when going to sleep.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The laptop lights up again because it's being prompted for user interaction, acting much like a mouse-movement or a keystroke in itself. Why not have those programs shutdown the computer when they have finished their job? Most AV programs and Backup programs have this feature built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried locking your computer screen (**Start+L**). If there is a message or a program popup that triggers the screen to wake so it asks for user interaction, it shouldn't do so if the screen is locked.

Comment: Yes, I actually do lock the screen whenever I run programs overnight. The screen always ends up turning back on for one reason or another.